# Linux Server to Printer -- Won't Print Color

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cups, printer

I'd like to automate a print task. I have a PDF stored on a Linux Server (Ubuntu 18.04) and I'd like to, from the command line, execute a print job of that PDF on a printer elsewhere on the subnet.

So far, I've gotten this to work fine. However, it won't print in color, and lpoptions only seems to list"Gray" and "Black" as print color options even though it is a color printer.

```
    PageSize/Media Size: Letter Legal Tabloid Executive w288h432 w360h576Statement SuperB A3 *A4 A5 B4 B5 C5 C6 DL COM10 Monarch
ColorModel/Color Model: *Gray Black
StpColorPrecision/Color Precision: Normal *Best
InputSlot/Media Source: *Standard ManualAdj Manual MultiPurposeAdj MultiPurpose UpperAdj Upper LowerAdj Lower LargeCapacityAdj LargeCapacity
StpQuality/Print Quality: None Draft *Standard High
Resolution/Resolution: 301x300dpi 150dpi 300dpi *600dpi
Duplex/2-Sided Printing: *None DuplexNoTumble DuplexTumble
```

I've run out of ideas. Anybody have any? Thanks.

Comment: Have you ensured the proper driver is being used?

Comment: The driver for my printer was not on the list, and I couldn't figure out how to install the .sh driver file provided by Xerox. However, I kept assigning the "wrong" drivers to my designated, default printer profile until the option for color populated my available settings. This may not be an ideal solution, but it solved my issue and it allowed me to print a color sheet using the "lp"command to a printer on the network.

Answer (score 0):

To test the printer and feel confident that it plays in color, try lp or lpr,whichever is in use. What I did on my Canon Pixma TR4500 was:

lp -oColorModel=cym xxx.jpeg,

and it printed fine. I wrote it this way because that's how the options were listed in lpoptions: ColorModel,Color Model: *rgb
You might have to match your lpoptions return.
Now I am gong to change the ppd to include cym, reinstall the printer and see what happens